# what is the difference between async and async* in dart?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am a beginner in dart. I am trying to understand deeply asynchronous tasks so i am faced to this confusion between async and async*.

If it's possible, I need a concret example of the uses of async* in dart.

Comment: Checkout [4th](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY) & [5th](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY) of the "Flutter in Focus" series by Flutter team. They've explained them pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` marks a function asynchronous so that you can perform some time consuming task (on the same isolate)

```
Future<int> foo() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  return 0;
}
```

`async*` is a generator which is used to generate a `Stream`.

```
Stream<int> bar() async* {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
}
```